# Post method issue, I can't upload more than 8 MB files using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can't upload more than 8 MB files in PHP. I have added below lines in `.htaccess` file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2048M
php_value post_max_size 2048M
```

This is working on localhost but not working on live server. I have contacted the support team of server and ask them to give rights to edit `php.ini` file but said you haven't any permission to update php.ini file.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: also I have made some changes in httpd.conf file `Allowoverride All`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webhost probably does not allow php.ini to be overridden by .htaccess. This is common on shared hosting. If you need to do large uploads you need to find a host that supports it or get a VPS.

Comment: Yes. Shared hosts can't modify their settings as it will affect every client on the server. This one example would mean the server doing more work which means every site suffers for it. Once you get past basic server needs you are faced with getting more powerful, and expensive, hosting.

Answer (score 0):

There are some upload libraries which support partial/chunked upload, you can circumvent hoster restrictions with that, cause it uses multiple requests to upload one file. I use something like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload most of the time when i have to handle big uploads.